# using NLTK package on Python35

Tags: python, nltk

I have successfully installed nltk on Python35 with no error. However, when I `import nltk` in python, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I know this has to do with 32 and 64 version. My Python is 64-bit version. However, I couldn't find any solution how to fix this without going back to Python 32-bit version. NLTK also does not have 32 or 64 version, it is a single package. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Answer (score 0):

As the NLTK installation instructions say:

> Install Python 3.5: http://www.python.org/downloads/ (avoid the 64-bit versions)

Currently, there is no way to run NLTK on python3 64-bit due to an issue the installer encounters.
If you want to keep your python 3 64bit, you can install a virtualenv and have both python 32-bit and 64 bit on your computer.
Check https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/ for details on virtualenv.